# Microsoft Office Communicator Automation API 2007 and and Send File

Tags: office-communicator

Is there any way to send files using the Microsoft Communicator API/SDK?

Comment: If you're happy with the answer below, could you mark it as Accepted, to help anyone else browsing these questions? Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

No, sending files is not supported by the Automation API.

If upgrading to Lync Server 2010 is an option, the [Lync SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=d98f0bf7-c82c-47f5-9f73-be3edbf30438) supports file transfers